# Generate subsets of elements from vector (NO NESTED LOOP)

Tags: c++, time-complexity, permutation

Let `v = {1,2,3,4,5,6}`. I want to generate by using `v` the following sets:

- 1 2 3 4 5 6
- 2 1 3 4 5 6
- 3 1 2 4 5 6
- 4 1 2 3 5 6
- 5 1 2 3 4 6
- 6 1 2 3 4 5

---

To achieve this goal I am using the following code, with a nested for loop:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6};
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << v[i] <<",";
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < v.size(); j++)
    { 
      if(i != j)
         cout << v[j] <<",";
    }
    cout << endl;
   }

 return 0;
}
```

---

Is there a better approach that can be used in order to generate the previous sets. At least not `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Your output locks the best complexity any algorithm could have to accomplish your result to O(n * n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an input list of size `n`, your output will always consist of `n*n` numbers. You cannot do better than O(n^2).

However, it seems to me that you merely swap the first and the first element, then the first and the second, then the first and the third etc.. 
You can hide the inner loop which prints a particular subset with an algorithm though, like in

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it ) {
        std::iter_swap( v.begin(), it );
        std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "," ) );
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: please let me test it to understand a little. sheesh some people are really smart mamamia

Answer (score 1):

To understand the lower bounds in your algorithm; Lets look at the transformation between the input and the output.

You are starting with a list of *N* elements and you end up with a list of *[N x (N - 1)]* elements.

Ignoring the logic to generate the output, the act of outputting itself is `O(N * (N - 1))` => O(n<sup>2</sup>).

In other words, you are outputting NxN items per the intial input on N. This will be O(n<sup>2</sup>) by definition.

Answer (score -1):

Here the inner loop is only used to print results:

```
int main()
{
  vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6};
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    int t = v[0];
    v[0] = v[i];
    v[i] = t;
    cout << v[0];
    for(unsigned int j = 1; j < v.size(); j++)
    { 
         cout << "," << v[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
   }

 return 0;
}
```